# Looping through JSON Data to Generate HTML

Tags: javascript, html, json

I have JSON data that looks like this:

```
data = {
  "tennis": [{
    "Description": "Insert description here.",
    "Price": 379.99,
    "ProductName": "Babolat Play Pure Drive",
  }, {
    "Description": "Insert description here.",
    "Price": 199.99,
    "ProductName": "Yonex AI 98 Tennis Racquet",
  }],
  "basketball": [{
    "Description": "Insert description here.",
    "Price": 64.99,
    "ProductName": "Wilson NCAA Solution Official Game Basketball",
  }, {
    "Description": "Insert description here.",
    "Price": 59.99,
    "ProductName": "Spalding NBA NeverFlat Size 7 Composite Leather Basketball",
  }]
}
```

I am using this data to generate HTML so it looks properly formatted and easily readable for the user. The way I am doing this is by creating a for loop to read through tennis and basketball categories. For example:

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.tennis.length; i++) {
  tennisProducts.push(data.tennis[i]);
  var tennisProductsTitle = tennisProducts[i].ProductName;
  var tennisProductsDescription = tennisProducts[i].Description;
  var tennisProductsPrice = tennisProducts[i].Price;
  var badge = document.createElement('div');
  badge.className = 'badge';
  badge.innerHTML =
    '<h1>' + tennisProductsTitle + '</h1>' +
    '<h2>' + tennisProductsDescription + '</h1>' +
    '<div class="options-only-phone">' +
    '<a class="service-provider-call" href="#" target="_blank"> Buy for $' + tennisProductsPrice + '</a>';
  document.getElementById('tennis-products-list').appendChild(badge);
}
```

How can I create one for loop that can read through both (or multiple) categories?

Here is my working example in this JSFiddle: **https://jsfiddle.net/dsk1279b/1**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Double loop, one to iterate the object properties, the next to iterate the array:

```
for (var key in data) {
    for (var i = 0; i < data[key].length; i++) {
        //HTML logic
    }
}
```

Final code:

```
for (var key in data) {
    for (var i = 0; i < data[key].length; i++) {
        var title = data[key][i].ProductName;
        var desc = data[key][i].Description;
        var price = data[key][i].Price;
        var badge = document.createElement('div');
        badge.className = 'badge';
        badge.innerHTML =
            '<h1>' + title + '</h1>' +
            '<h2>' + desc + '</h1>' +
            '<div class="options-only-phone">' +
            '<a class="service-provider-call" href="#" target="_blank"> Buy for $' + price + '</a>';
        //I gave the div the same ID's as the keys in the object for ease
        document.getElementById(key).appendChild(badge);
    }
}
```

```js
data = {
  "tennis": [{
    "Description": "Insert description here.",
    "Price": 379.99,
    "ProductName": "Babolat Play Pure Drive",
  }, {
    "Description": "Insert description here.",
    "Price": 199.99,
    "ProductName": "Yonex AI 98 Tennis Racquet",
  }],
  "basketball": [{
    "Description": "Insert description here.",
    "Price": 64.99,
    "ProductName": "Wilson NCAA Solution Official Game Basketball",
  }, {
    "Description": "Insert description here.",
    "Price": 59.99,
    "ProductName": "Spalding NBA NeverFlat Size 7 Composite Leather Basketball",
  }]
}

for (var key in data) {
  for (var i = 0; i < data[key].length; i++) {
    var title = data[key][i].ProductName;
    var desc = data[key][i].Description;
    var price = data[key][i].Price;
    var badge = document.createElement('div');
    badge.className = 'badge';
    badge.innerHTML =
      '<h1>' + title + '</h1>' +
      '<h2>' + desc + '</h1>' +
      '<div class="options-only-phone">' +
      '<a class="service-provider-call" href="#" target="_blank"> Buy for $' + price + '</a>';
    document.getElementById(key).appendChild(badge);
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  line-height: 125%;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 0.875em;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

h2,
a {
  font-size: 0.750em;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-weight: normal;
}

a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.badge {
  border-radius: 2px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  padding: 12px;
  margin: 12px 0;
}

.badge:hover {
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
```

```html
<div id="tennis">

</div>

<hr>

<div id="basketball">

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. Definitely a cleaner approach.

Answer (score 0):

tymeJV has a good approach, but this can be made even easier.

```
for(var product in data) {
    // logic
}
```

If you look at your data, you have an object that we're already iterating over in key/value form. 
Since you have arrays of items per key, you can use the `Array.forEach()` function.

```
for(var product in data) {
    // current is the current object in the array
    data[product].forEach(function(current){
        //HTML logic
    })
}
```

You change the place where you're appending the html template, so I would recommend updating your data object to be something like this:

```
data = {
  "tennis": {
    "products: [
        {
            "Description": "Insert description here.",
            "Price": 379.99,
            "ProductName": "Babolat Play Pure Drive"
        }, 
        {
            "Description": "Insert description here.",
            "Price": 199.99,
            "ProductName": "Yonex AI 98 Tennis Racquet"
        }
    ],
    "templateTarget": '#tennis-products-list'
  }
  "basketball": 
    "products":  [
        {
            "Description": "Insert description here.",
            "Price": 64.99,
            "ProductName": "Wilson NCAA Solution Official Game Basketball"
        }, 
        {
            "Description": "Insert description here.",
            "Price": 59.99,
            "ProductName": "Spalding NBA NeverFlat Size 7 Composite Leather Basketball"
        }
    ],
      "templateTarget": '#basketball-products-list'
}
```

Something like that is going to allow you to do this:

```
for(var product in data) {
    // current is the current object in the array
    product.forEach(function(current){
        var badge = document.createElement('div');
        badge.className = 'badge';
        badge.innerHTML =
          '<h1>' + current.productName + '</h1>' +
          '<h2>' + current.description + '</h1>' +
          '<div class="options-only-phone">' +
          '<a class="service-provider-call" href="#" target="_blank"> Buy for $' + current.price +  '</a>';
        document.getElementById(current.templateTarget).appendChild(badge);
    })
}
```

This can be further optimized by having that giant html string hidden in a `script` tag with `type="text/x-template"` (since the browser ignores script types it doesn't understand) and grabbing it with the innerHTML function by referencing the `id` property on the script tag.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Flatten the data to a single array of values with `category` as a property:

```
var _data = Object.keys(data).reduce(
              (m,c) => m.concat(data[c].map(
                (i) => (i.category = c) && i))
           , []);

console.log(_data);
```

Use flattened array for UI:

```
_data.forEach((d) => {
  var badge = document.createElement('div');
  badge.className = 'badge';
  badge.innerHTML = [
    '<h1>',
    d.ProductName,
    '</h1><h2>',
    d.Description,
    '</h1><div class="options-only-phone">',
    '<a class="service-provider-call" href="#" target="_blank"> Buy for $',
    d.Price,
    '</a>'].join('');
  document.getElementById(d.category + '-products-list').appendChild(badge);
})
```

```js
'use strict';
var data = {
  "tennis": [{
    "Description": "Insert description here.",
    "Price": 379.99,
    "ProductName": "Babolat Play Pure Drive",
  }, {
    "Description": "Insert description here.",
    "Price": 199.99,
    "ProductName": "Yonex AI 98 Tennis Racquet",
  }],
  "basketball": [{
    "Description": "Insert description here.",
    "Price": 64.99,
    "ProductName": "Wilson NCAA Solution Official Game Basketball",
  }, {
    "Description": "Insert description here.",
    "Price": 59.99,
    "ProductName": "Spalding NBA NeverFlat Size 7 Composite Leather Basketball",
  }]
}


var _data = Object.keys(data).reduce((m,c) => m.concat(data[c].map((i) => (i.category = c) && i) ), []);

console.log(_data);


_data.forEach((d) => {
  var badge = document.createElement('div');
  badge.className = 'badge';
  badge.innerHTML = [
    '<h1>',
    d.ProductName,
    '</h1><h2>',
    d.Description,
    '</h1><div class="options-only-phone">',
    '<a class="service-provider-call" href="#" target="_blank"> Buy for $',
    d.Price,
    '</a>'].join('');
  document.getElementById(d.category + '-products-list').appendChild(badge);
})
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  line-height: 125%;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 0.875em;
  padding: 0; margin: 0;
}

h2, a {
  font-size: 0.750em;
  padding: 0; margin: 0;
  font-weight: normal;
}

a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.badge {
  border-radius: 2px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  padding: 12px;
  margin: 12px 0;
}

.badge:hover {
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
```

```html
<div id="tennis-products-list">

</div>

<hr>

<div id="basketball-products-list">

</div>
```