# How can I append my ajax data into multiple divs that are already created?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I'm creating an app that uses a news API and I'm trying to append the data that I get back inside my already created Bootstrap columns.  I'm not sure on how to go about this.  I would like to display the image, title, and description. Not sure if it would be easier to just scratch the HTML and dynamically create rows instead with an If statement and a for loop that runs through each row to display the desired amount of rows and images? If anyone could point me in the right direction I would greatly appreciate it!

```js
window.onload = function() {

  API_Call.displayTenArticles();

};

var API_Call = {

  generateRandomSource: function() {

    // Array to store all external news sources from news API
    var allSources = ["abc-news-au", "al-jazeera-english", "bbc-news", "bloomberg", "cnbc", "cnn", "google-news", "breitbart-news", "daily-mail", "reuters", "the-guardian-uk", "the-new-york-times", "the-wall-street-journal", "time", "the-washington-post"];
    // Var to store randomly generated number based off of length of allSources API
    var randomSource = Math.floor(Math.random() * allSources.length);
    // Selected newsource generated on onload
    var selectedSource = allSources[randomSource];
    // Function to select random news source
    // Function to generate 10 images to DOM

    return selectedSource;

  },

  displayTenArticles: function() {

    selectedSource = API_Call.generateRandomSource();

    // API_Call.NYT_API_Call(selectedSource);

    API_Call.NEWS_API_Call(selectedSource);

  },

  parse_Ajax_JSON: function(response) { // Variable to store number of results

    var numberResults = 6;
    // Variable to hold data returned from API
    var results = response.articles;
    console.log(results);
    // Empty display div whenever new high level object is selected
    $("#display-articles").empty();
    // forLoop to iterate through functions 10 times
    for (var i = 0; i < numberResults; i++) {
      // Create div to store generated news articles
      var displayedArticles = $("");
      // Grab title from API
      var articleTitle = results[i].title;
      console.log(articleTitle);
      // Grab description from API
      var descriptionTitle = results[i].description;
      console.log(descriptionTitle);

      //IMAGE Display

      var image = results[i].urlToImage;
      console.log(image);

      // Saving the image_original_url property
      // var imageDiv = $("<div>");
      // var displayedArticles = $("<div>");
      // Creating and storing an image tag
      var articleImage = $("<img>");
      articleImage.attr("src", image);
      // articleImage.attr("class", "gif");    
      displayedArticles.append(articleImage);

      // $("#display-articles").prepend(imageDiv);

      //URL Display
      var articleURL = results[i].url;
      var articleLink = $("<a>");
      articleLink.attr('href', articleURL);
      console.log(articleURL);
      var pThree = articleLink.html(articleURL);


      // Paragraph to store article title
      var pOne = $("<p>").text("Article Title: " + articleTitle);
      // Paragraph to store description of article
      var pTwo = $("<p>").text("Article Descriptoin" + descriptionTitle);
      // Append to displayedArticles div
      // descriptionTitle.append(pTwo);
      displayedArticles.append(pOne);
      displayedArticles.append(pTwo);
      displayedArticles.append(pThree);
      // Append to display-articles div
      $("#display-articles").append(displayedArticles);
      // $("#display-articles").append(descriptionTitle);
    }

  },

  NEWS_API_Call: function() {

    var article = $(this).attr("data-name");
    var queryURL = "https://newsapi.org/v1/articles?source=" + selectedSource + "&sortBy=top&apiKey=01aed6729dc84b87b67d8eca2e2a711b"
    // ajax call to news API
    $.ajax({
      url: queryURL,
      method: 'GET',
    }).done(function(response) {
      console.log(response);

      API_Call.parse_Ajax_JSON(response);

    });

  },

  Blog_API_Call: function(selectedSource) {

    // var article = $(this).attr("data-name");
    /*
      var queryURL = "https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/blogs/blogId/posts/search?q=query" +  selectedSource;
      // ajax call to news API
      $.ajax({
        url:queryURL,
        method: 'GET',
      }).done(function handleResponse(selectedSource) {
        console.log(response);
        document.getElementById("content").innerHTML += "<h1>" + response.title + "</h1>" + response.content;
      }
      
      });
            
       */


  },

};

$("#category-switch").click(function() {
  $('.flip').find(".card").toggleClass("flipped");
  $('.articles').hide();
  $('.blogs').show();
  return false;
});
```

```css
/*Basic Setup*/

* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background: #fff;
}

.row {
  padding-top: 10px;
}

.titleChange {
  display: none;
}

footer {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 1rem;
  background-color: #efefef;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.blogs {
  display: none;
}

.os-animation {
  opacity: 1!important;
}


/*----------Nav Bar, Links, Sign-Up DropDown-----------*/

#logo {
  max-height: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}

.navbar {
  border: none;
  border-radius: none;
  background: #262626;
  box-shadow: 1px 3px #000;
  border-radius: 0px;
}

.navbar-logo {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}


/*----------Category Switch animation-----------*/

.flip {
  -webkit-perspective: 800;
  -ms-perspective: 800;
  -moz-perspective: 800;
  -o-perspective: 800;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
}

.flip .card.flipped {
  transform: rotatey(-180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotatey(-180deg);
  /* IE 9 */
  -moz-transform: rotatey(-180deg);
  /* Firefox */
  -webkit-transform: rotatey(-180deg);
  /* Safari and Chrome */
  -o-transform: rotatey(-180deg);
  /* Opera */
}

.flip .card {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
  -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -moz-transition: 0.5s;
  -ms-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -ms-transition: 0.5s;
  -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -o-transition: 0.5s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.flip .card .face {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  font-family: Georgia;
  font-size: 3em;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 200px;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  /* W3C */
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  /* Safari & Chrome */
  -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
  /* Firefox */
  -ms-backface-visibility: hidden;
  /* Internet Explorer */
  -o-backface-visibility: hidden;
  /* Opera */
}

.flip .card .front {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  background: black;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.flip .card .back {
  background: blue;
  background: white;
  color: black;
  cursor: pointer;
  transform: rotatey(-180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotatey(-180deg);
  /* IE 9 */
  -moz-transform: rotatey(-180deg);
  /* Firefox */
  -webkit-transform: rotatey(-180deg);
  /* Safari and Chrome */
  -o-transform: rotatey(-180deg);
  /* Opera */
}


/*--------------Article Page ---------------*/

#display-articles {
  text-align: center;
  width: 400px;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>SorceLess Home</title>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./assets/css/style.css">
  <link href="./assets/css/animate.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./assets/css/waypoints.css">
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>

  <header class="text-center">
    <nav class="navbar os-animation" data-os-animation="bounceInDown" data-os-animation-delay=".1s" role="navigation">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-logo">
          <img id="logo" class="img-responsive" src="./assets/img/sourceLesslogo.png">
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </nav>
    <div class="row text-center os-animation" data-os-animation="bounceInDown" data-os-animation-delay=".3s">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <h1 class="articles">Articles</h1>
        <h1 class="blogs">Blogs</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>
  <div class="container text-center">
    <section id="categories text-center">
      <div class="row os-animation card" onclick="flip()" data-os-animation="fadeInRight" data-os-animation-delay=".3s">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <div class="flip">
            <div class="card">
              <div class="face front">
                <p id="title">Title</p>
                <div id="categories"></div>
              </div>
              <div class="face back">
                <p id="title">Title</p>
                <div id="category"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <div class="flip">
            <div class="card">
              <div class="face front">
                <p id="title">Title</p>
                <div id="display-articles"></div>
                <p id="description"></p>
              </div>
              <div class="face back">
                <p id="title">Title</p>
                <div id="category"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <div class="flip">
            <div class="card">
              <div class="face front">
                <p id="title">Title</p>
                <div id="display-articles"></div>
              </div>
              <div class="face back">
                <p id="title">Title</p>
                <div id="category"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row os-animation card" onclick="flip()" data-os-animation="fadeInRight" data-os-animation-delay=".3s">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <div class="flip">
            <div class="card">
              <div class="face front">
                <p id="title">Title</p>
                <div id="category"></div>
              </div>
              <div class="face back">
                <p id="title">Title</p>
                <div id="category"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <div class="flip">
            <div class="card">
              <div class="face front">
                <p id="title">Title</p>
                <div id="category"></div>
              </div>
              <div class="face back">
                <p id="title">Title</p>
                <div id="category"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <div class="flip">
            <div class="card">
              <div class="face front">
                <p id="title">Title</p>
                <div id="category"></div>
              </div>
              <div class="face back">
                <p id="title">Title</p>
                <div id="category"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
    <div class="row text-center">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <button class="btn btn-primary os-animation" data-os-animation="bounceInUp" data-os-animation-delay=".3s" id="category-switch">Click to change sources</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--<footer>
  <div class="row text-center">
   <div class="col-lg-12">
    <p>@SourceLess 2017</p>
   </div>
  </div>
</footer>-->
  </div>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src=./assets/js/jquery.waypoints.min.js></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src=./assets/js/waypoints.js></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="./assets/js/app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Do you really need to hardcode your html before getting data from ajax. why can'y you create your html code after ajax by looping it?

Comment: I coded the HTML before getting the ajax data.  Just starting to learn this is in school so it's all pretty new to me.  Thought there might be a way to just implement it into the HTML.  Do you have any suggestions on how to go about creating dynamic rows?

Comment: If you create html before getting data you need to give individual id's for all the articles. using id's you need to append data to the divs

Comment: Yea that's what I'm having trouble with.  Not sure how to give each article and individual id and append the data into the divs.  I will have to do some research on creating dynamic rows.  Sounds like a better option.

Comment: you may take a  look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34907982/looping-through-json-data-to-generate-html

Comment: Still a little confused on dynamically adding them.  If I do it that wat my animation doesn't work.  I would like to try and append them to specific id's as well and see if that may be a better solution.  Is there any way you could help me get started or maybe provide me with some syntax to look up.  I must not be googling the question right.  Thanks for your help I appreciate it.

Answer (score -1):

why don't you use handlebars or mustache for templating??

It will be easy and good thing to learn since it will keep your code very clean and readable.

let me know if you need any help.

Comment: I will have to check those out. I'm always down to learn new things.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/16537413)

Comment: @suraj I think my sol pretty much answers the question, it is just that asker does not want to adopt it.

Comment: So would I just put the JSON data inside the quotes where the "title" is at?

Comment: So  you will have your template just like I have created  one inside 
 <script id="template" type="text/x-handlebars-template"></script>

whatever data you want to populate should be kept inside {{}}

now in your js file after ajax call once you get the response iterate over it just the way i have done over my array of object and set those vars.