# How to display fetched data in html

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I am fetching todo list, I am wondering why it gives me `undefined` when I do this

```
.then((response) => {
  response.json();
  }
```

it works with

```
.then(response => response.json())
```

Why is this happening?

Also, when I'm fetching the data, they are objects and I save them in array

```js
  completed: true,
  id: 199,
  title: "numquam repellendus a magnam",
  userId: 10
},
```

etc..

Now, I have html template for this, I'd like to load this in my html where my styles are, how can I do this?

```html
<div class="card">
<p>//Want Id here</p>
<strong>// Want Title here</strong>
</div>
```

fetching code:

```js
let todos = [];

function fetchData() {
    fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos').then(response => response.json())
  .then((json) => {
    todos = json;
    console.log(todos);
  })
  }

fetchData();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.then((response) => {
  response.json();
})
```

This function above doesn't return anything. It does `response.json()` but does not return it.

You need to add `return` so it gets passed to the next `.then()` :

```
.then((response) => {
  return response.json();
})
```

This will work. But ES6 allows a nice syntactic sugar :

```
.then(response => response.json())
```

Without the braces, `response.json()` will be returned, without you having to explicitly write `return`.

This is the difference between braces and no braces.

But there's an even nicer way to deal with it, using async/await :

```
let todos = [];

async function fetchData() {
    const response = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos');
    const todos = await response.json();
    console.log(todos);
}

fetchData();
```

Comment: Also, how can I display the fetched items in html? I want to display entire array with the elements which are in my html. Do I need a function with seperate loop?

Comment: There are basic tutorials everywhere for this. Just google it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34907982/looping-through-json-data-to-generate-html

Comment: Can you see this https://jsfiddle.net/17mhcuz8/ , I do not know at all why it's not logging the loop, I also tried with forEach

Comment: Well, obviously because you are trying to loop over `todos` before it is populated. You are looping over `[]`, and _then_ the array gets filled. `todos = json; loopitems();`

Comment: so I need to move everything to the function above right?

Comment: Well you need to do things in chronological order :)

Comment: So I kinda got it to work, https://jsfiddle.net/h53c8e6g/1/ but I'm having `[object HTMLDivElement]` , do you know what might be the issue?

Comment: You have an extra `+` after `</h2>`

Comment: No worries, glad I could help

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use [template literals](https://css-tricks.com/template-literals)?

My suggestion:

```js
let todos = [];

fetchData();

function fetchData() {
  fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => todos = json)
    .then(() => {
      for (let item of todos) {
        toAppend.innerHTML += `
<div class="card">
<p>${item.id}</p>
<h2>${item.title}</h2>
</div>
`;
      }
    });
}
```

```html
<div id="toAppend"></div>
```

Anyway, if you only need to show fetched items, an alternative, easier solution can be:

```js
const fetchData = async() => (await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos')).json();

fetchData()
  .then(data => {
    for (let item of data) {
      toAppend.innerHTML += `
<div class="card">
<p>${item.id}</p>
<h2>${item.title}</h2>
</div>
`;
    }
  });
```

```html
<div id="toAppend"></div>
```

Here `fetchData()` is an [asynchronous function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function).