# Complete a product card in javascript/JSON

Tags: javascript, json

I am new to javascript.
I am looking for a way to retrieve the information from a local server running on Node:

*0
**colors**
0   "Tan"
1   "Chocolate"
2   "Black"
3   "White"
**_id** "5be9c8541c9d440000665243"
**name**    "Norbert"
**price**   2900
**imageUrl**    "http://localhost:3000/images/teddy_1.jpg"
**description** "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua."

1
**colors**
0   "Pale brown"
1   "Dark brown"
2   "White"
**_id** "5beaa8bf1c9d440000a57d94"
**name**    "Arnold"
**price**   3900
**imageUrl**    "http://localhost:3000/images/teddy_2.jpg"
**description** "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua."*

I'm looking for a way to display them as HTML in a div. Here is my code for the moment, it does not display an error but I am unable to display the array elements ...
Any ideas?
Thanks for your suggestions!

```js
const fetchPromise = fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/teddies');

const main = document.getElementById("clothes-box");

fetchPromise.then(response => {
  return response.json();
}).then(products => {
  main.appendChild = listOfNames(products);
})

function listOfNames(products) {
  const listHtml = document.createElement('ul')

  products.forEach(function(product) {
    const listItem = document.createElement('li');
    listItem.textContent = product.name
    listHtml.appendChild(listItem)
  })

  return listHtml
}
```

Comment: Please add an example for `products` in a well-formatted way (e.g. the output of `console.log(JSON.stringify(products, null, 2))`)

Comment: `main.appendChild = listOfNames(products)` - `.appendChild` is a method -> `main.appendChild(listOfNames)`, just like in the `.forEach()`: `listHtml.appendChild(listItem)`

Comment: Hi, Andreas, here's what I get with console.log(JSON.stringify(products, null, 2))                                                                                                                                         [
  {
    "colors": [
      "Tan",
      "Chocolate",
      "Black",
      "White"
    ],
    "_id": "5be9c8541c9d440000665243",
    "name": "Norbert",
    "price": 2900,
    "imageUrl": "http://localhost:3000/images/teddy_1.jpg",
    "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor."
  },

]

Comment: Don't add relevant info in the comments. [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66686544/edit) your question and replace _"0 colors ..."_ with the output (which in this case should be formatted as code).

Comment: But nevertheless you just have to fix the typo mentioned in my second comment and it should work.

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66596791/how-to-display-fetched-data-in-html/66597794#66597794

Comment: @AbsoluteBeginner What does this have to do with _"it does not display an error but I am unable to display the array elements"_? OPs script works when the typo got fixed.

Comment: @Andreas I've just suggested an alternative (and, IMHO, better) way to fetch and display data. Without detracting anything from your correct comment.

Comment: Thanks for your advices, it's fixed now. Sorry for not being  clear, that was for first contribution to stackoverflow. Thanks a lot!