# Is there a way to loop through JSON data and display it in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I am trying to great a weather app using The Weather API. I have managed to get the information that I need from the JSON and display it in HTML.

I would not like to get the hourly weather from the JSON and display it from each hour. I thought about doing this within a loop and displaying it that way but am unsure how to write it.

Here is the JSON

```js
"hour": [
                    {
                        "time_epoch": 1622070000,
                        "time": "2021-05-27 00:00",
                        "temp_c": 7.6,
                        "temp_f": 45.7,
                        "is_day": 0,
                        "condition": {
                            "text": "Partly cloudy",
                            "icon": "//cdn.weatherapi.com/weather/64x64/night/116.png",
                            "code": 1003
                        },
                        "wind_mph": 4.0,
                        "wind_kph": 6.5,
                        "wind_degree": 231,
                        "wind_dir": "SW",
                        "pressure_mb": 1018.0,
                        "pressure_in": 30.5,
                        "precip_mm": 0.0,
                        "precip_in": 0.0,
                        "humidity": 89,
                        "cloud": 5,
                        "feelslike_c": 6.6,
                        "feelslike_f": 43.9,
                        "windchill_c": 6.6,
                        "windchill_f": 43.9,
                        "heatindex_c": 7.6,
                        "heatindex_f": 45.7,
                        "dewpoint_c": 5.9,
                        "dewpoint_f": 42.6,
                        "will_it_rain": 0,
                        "chance_of_rain": "0",
                        "will_it_snow": 0,
                        "chance_of_snow": "0",
                        "vis_km": 10.0,
                        "vis_miles": 6.0,
                        "gust_mph": 7.6,
                        "gust_kph": 12.2,
                        "uv": 1.0
                    },
                    {
                        "time_epoch": 1622073600,
                        "time": "2021-05-27 01:00",
                        "temp_c": 7.4,
                        "temp_f": 45.3,
                        "is_day": 0,
                        "condition": {
                            "text": "Partly cloudy",
                            "icon": "//cdn.weatherapi.com/weather/64x64/night/116.png",
                            "code": 1003
                        },
                        "wind_mph": 4.3,
                        "wind_kph": 6.8,
                        "wind_degree": 213,
                        "wind_dir": "SSW",
                        "pressure_mb": 1018.0,
                        "pressure_in": 30.5,
                        "precip_mm": 0.0,
                        "precip_in": 0.0,
                        "humidity": 88,
                        "cloud": 5,
                        "feelslike_c": 6.2,
                        "feelslike_f": 43.2,
                        "windchill_c": 6.2,
                        "windchill_f": 43.2,
                        "heatindex_c": 7.4,
                        "heatindex_f": 45.3,
                        "dewpoint_c": 5.6,
                        "dewpoint_f": 42.1,
                        "will_it_rain": 0,
                        "chance_of_rain": "0",
                        "will_it_snow": 0,
                        "chance_of_snow": "0",
                        "vis_km": 10.0,
                        "vis_miles": 6.0,
                        "gust_mph": 8.1,
                        "gust_kph": 13.0,
                        "uv": 1.0
                    },
                    {
                        "time_epoch": 1622077200,
                        "time": "2021-05-27 02:00",
                        "temp_c": 7.1,
                        "temp_f": 44.8,
                        "is_day": 0,
                        "condition": {
                            "text": "Partly cloudy",
                            "icon": "//cdn.weatherapi.com/weather/64x64/night/116.png",
                            "code": 1003
                        },
                        "wind_mph": 4.5,
                        "wind_kph": 7.2,
                        "wind_degree": 196,
                        "wind_dir": "SSW",
                        "pressure_mb": 1018.0,
                        "pressure_in": 30.5,
                        "precip_mm": 0.0,
                        "precip_in": 0.0,
                        "humidity": 88,
                        "cloud": 5,
                        "feelslike_c": 5.9,
                        "feelslike_f": 42.6,
                        "windchill_c": 5.9,
                        "windchill_f": 42.6,
                        "heatindex_c": 7.1,
                        "heatindex_f": 44.8,
                        "dewpoint_c": 5.2,
                        "dewpoint_f": 41.4,
                        "will_it_rain": 0,
                        "chance_of_rain": "0",
                        "will_it_snow": 0,
                        "chance_of_snow": "0",
                        "vis_km": 10.0,
                        "vis_miles": 6.0,
                        "gust_mph": 8.7,
                        "gust_kph": 14.0,
                        "uv": 1.0
                    },
                    {
                        "time_epoch": 1622080800,
                        "time": "2021-05-27 03:00",
                        "temp_c": 6.9,
                        "temp_f": 44.4,
                        "is_day": 0,
                        "condition": {
                            "text": "Partly cloudy",
                            "icon": "//cdn.weatherapi.com/weather/64x64/night/116.png",
                            "code": 1003
                        },
                        "wind_mph": 4.7,
                        "wind_kph": 7.6,
                        "wind_degree": 178,
                        "wind_dir": "S",
                        "pressure_mb": 1018.0,
                        "pressure_in": 30.5,
                        "precip_mm": 0.0,
                        "precip_in": 0.0,
                        "humidity": 87,
                        "cloud": 5,
                        "feelslike_c": 5.5,
                        "feelslike_f": 41.9,
                        "windchill_c": 5.5,
                        "windchill_f": 41.9,
                        "heatindex_c": 6.9,
                        "heatindex_f": 44.4,
                        "dewpoint_c": 4.9,
                        "dewpoint_f": 40.8,
                        "will_it_rain": 0,
                        "chance_of_rain": "0",
                        "will_it_snow": 0,
                        "chance_of_snow": "0",
                        "vis_km": 10.0,
                        "vis_miles": 6.0,
                        "gust_mph": 9.2,
                        "gust_kph": 14.8,
                        "uv": 1.0
                    },
                    {
                        "time_epoch": 1622084400,
                        "time": "2021-05-27 04:00",
                        "temp_c": 7.3,
                        "temp_f": 45.1,
                        "is_day": 0,
                        "condition": {
                            "text": "Partly cloudy",
                            "icon": "//cdn.weatherapi.com/weather/64x64/night/116.png",
                            "code": 1003
                        },
                        "wind_mph": 5.4,
                        "wind_kph": 8.6,
                        "wind_degree": 171,
                        "wind_dir": "S",
                        "pressure_mb": 1018.0,
                        "pressure_in": 30.5,
                        "precip_mm": 0.0,
                        "precip_in": 0.0,
                        "humidity": 86,
                        "cloud": 5,
                        "feelslike_c": 5.7,
                        "feelslike_f": 42.3,
                        "windchill_c": 5.7,
                        "windchill_f": 42.3,
                        "heatindex_c": 7.3,
                        "heatindex_f": 45.1,
                        "dewpoint_c": 5.1,
                        "dewpoint_f": 41.2,
                        "will_it_rain": 0,
                        "chance_of_rain": "0",
                        "will_it_snow": 0,
                        "chance_of_snow": "0",
                        "vis_km": 10.0,
                        "vis_miles": 6.0,
                        "gust_mph": 10.1,
                        "gust_kph": 16.2,
                        "uv": 1.0
                    },
                    {
                        "time_epoch": 1622088000,
                        "time": "2021-05-27 05:00",
                        "temp_c": 7.6,
                        "temp_f": 45.7,
                        "is_day": 1,
                        "condition": {
                            "text": "Partly cloudy",
                            "icon": "//cdn.weatherapi.com/weather/64x64/day/116.png",
                            "code": 1003
                        },
                        "wind_mph": 6.0,
                        "wind_kph": 9.7,
                        "wind_degree": 163,
                        "wind_dir": "SSE",
                        "pressure_mb": 1018.0,
                        "pressure_in": 30.5,
                        "precip_mm": 0.0,
                        "precip_in": 0.0,
                        "humidity": 85,
                        "cloud": 5,
                        "feelslike_c": 5.9,
                        "feelslike_f": 42.6,
                        "windchill_c": 5.9,
                        "windchill_f": 42.6,
                        "heatindex_c": 7.6,
                        "heatindex_f": 45.7,
                        "dewpoint_c": 5.2,
                        "dewpoint_f": 41.4,
                        "will_it_rain": 0,
                        "chance_of_rain": "0",
                        "will_it_snow": 0,
                        "chance_of_snow": "0",
                        "vis_km": 10.0,
                        "vis_miles": 6.0,
                        "gust_mph": 10.7,
                        "gust_kph": 17.3,
                        "uv": 3.0
                    },
                    {
                        "time_epoch": 1622091600,
                        "time": "2021-05-27 06:00",
                        "temp_c": 8.0,
                        "temp_f": 46.4,
                        "is_day": 1,
                        "condition": {
                            "text": "Partly cloudy",
                            "icon": "//cdn.weatherapi.com/weather/64x64/day/116.png",
                            "code": 1003
                        },
                        "wind_mph": 6.7,
                        "wind_kph": 10.8,
                        "wind_degree": 156,
                        "wind_dir": "SSE",
                        "pressure_mb": 1018.0,
                        "pressure_in": 30.5,
                        "precip_mm": 0.0,
                        "precip_in": 0.0,
                        "humidity": 84,
                        "cloud": 6,
                        "feelslike_c": 6.1,
                        "feelslike_f": 43.0,
                        "windchill_c": 6.1,
                        "windchill_f": 43.0,
                        "heatindex_c": 8.0,
                        "heatindex_f": 46.4,
                        "dewpoint_c": 5.4,
                        "dewpoint_f": 41.7,
                        "will_it_rain": 0,
                        "chance_of_rain": "0",
                        "will_it_snow": 0,
                        "chance_of_snow": "0",
                        "vis_km": 10.0,
                        "vis_miles": 6.0,
                        "gust_mph": 11.6,
                        "gust_kph": 18.7,
                        "uv": 3.0
                    },
                    {
                        "time_epoch": 1622095200,
                        "time": "2021-05-27 07:00",
                        "temp_c": 9.3,
                        "temp_f": 48.7,
                        "is_day": 1,
                        "condition": {
                            "text": "Partly cloudy",
                            "icon": "//cdn.weatherapi.com/weather/64x64/day/116.png",
                            "code": 1003
                        },
                        "wind_mph": 7.6,
                        "wind_kph": 12.2,
                        "wind_degree": 155,
                        "wind_dir": "SSE",
                        "pressure_mb": 1018.0,
                        "pressure_in": 30.5,
                        "precip_mm": 0.0,
                        "precip_in": 0.0,
                        "humidity": 82,
                        "cloud": 14,
                        "feelslike_c": 7.5,
                        "feelslike_f": 45.5,
                        "windchill_c": 7.5,
                        "windchill_f": 45.5,
                        "heatindex_c": 9.3,
                        "heatindex_f": 48.7,
                        "dewpoint_c": 6.3,
                        "dewpoint_f": 43.3,
                        "will_it_rain": 0,
                        "chance_of_rain": "0",
                        "will_it_snow": 0,
                        "chance_of_snow": "0",
                        "vis_km": 10.0,
                        "vis_miles": 6.0,
                        "gust_mph": 12.3,
                        "gust_kph": 19.8,
                        "uv": 3.0
                    }
```

I like to display the icon and time.

Here is what I have written to display the first hour.

```js
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: api + "forecast.json?key=" + apiKey + "&q=" + position.coords.latitude+ "," + position.coords.longitude,
      dataType: 'json',
      timeout: 0,
      success: (parsed_json) => {

        const hourImage = parsed_json['forecast']['forecastday'][0]['hour'][0]['condition']['icon'];
        const time = parsed_json['forecast']['forecastday'][0]['hour'][0]['time'];
        const hourHigh = parsed_json['forecast']['forecastday'][0]['hour'][0]['temp_c'];
        

        const hourImg = document.createElement("img"); 
        hourImg.src = "http:" + hourImage;
        const hourImageText = document.getElementById("box");
        hourImageText.appendChild(hourImg);
       
        const timeText = document.getElementById("title");
        timeText.innerText = time.split(" ")[1];

        const hourHighText = document.getElementById("card-text");
        hourHighText.innerHTML = hourHigh + "&#176;";
          
      }
    });
```

I would like to loop through and display each hour within similar HTML

```html
<div class="card align-items-center justify-content-center text-center" style="width: 7rem;">
    
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 id="title"></h5>
      <div id="box"></div>
      <p id="card-text"></p>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

After looking at one of the answers I was given I have tried the following but it doesn't seem to work.

```js
  for (let key in parsed_json) {
          for (let i = 0; i < parsed_json[key].length; i++) {
            const time = parsed_json[key][i]['forecast']['forecastday'][0]['hour'][0]['time'];
            const hourImage = parsed_json[key][i]['forecast']['forecastday'][0]['hour'][0]['condition']['icon'];
            const hourHigh = parsed_json[key][i]['forecast']['forecastday'][0]['hour'][0]['temp_c'];

            const hour = document.createElement('div');
            hour.className = "card align-items-center justify-content-center text-center";
            hour.innerHTML =  '<div class="card-body">' +'<h5>' + time + '</h5>' + '</div>';

            document.getElementById(key).appendChild(hour);

          }
        }
```

Comment: Check this answer! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34907982/looping-through-json-data-to-generate-html

Comment: thanks, I will have a look at this

Comment: this code doesn't seem to work

Comment: Hi , can you show proper json structure ?

Comment: i have added it to my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.each` loop to iterate through your json .Then , inside loop get values using keyname i.e : `v.time` this will give you time same for other and then add generated html inside your dom.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
//this is just for demo ..
var parsed_json = {
  "hour": [{
      "time_epoch": 1622070000,
      "time": "2021-05-27 00:00",
      "temp_c": 7.6,
      "temp_f": 45.7,
      "is_day": 0,
      "condition": {
        "text": "Partly cloudy",
        "icon": "//cdn.weatherapi.com/weather/64x64/night/116.png",
        "code": 1003
      },
      "wind_mph": 4.0,
      "wind_kph": 6.5,
      "wind_degree": 231,
      "wind_dir": "SW",
      "pressure_mb": 1018.0,
      "pressure_in": 30.5,
      "precip_mm": 0.0,
      "precip_in": 0.0,
      "humidity": 89,
      "cloud": 5,
      "feelslike_c": 6.6,
      "feelslike_f": 43.9,
      "windchill_c": 6.6,
      "windchill_f": 43.9,
      "heatindex_c": 7.6,
      "heatindex_f": 45.7,
      "dewpoint_c": 5.9,
      "dewpoint_f": 42.6,
      "will_it_rain": 0,
      "chance_of_rain": "0",
      "will_it_snow": 0,
      "chance_of_snow": "0",
      "vis_km": 10.0,
      "vis_miles": 6.0,
      "gust_mph": 7.6,
      "gust_kph": 12.2,
      "uv": 1.0
    },
    {
      "time_epoch": 1622073600,
      "time": "2021-05-27 01:00",
      "temp_c": 7.4,
      "temp_f": 45.3,
      "is_day": 0,
      "condition": {
        "text": "Partly cloudy",
        "icon": "//cdn.weatherapi.com/weather/64x64/night/116.png",
        "code": 1003
      },
      "wind_mph": 4.3,
      "wind_kph": 6.8,
      "wind_degree": 213,
      "wind_dir": "SSW",
      "pressure_mb": 1018.0,
      "pressure_in": 30.5,
      "precip_mm": 0.0,
      "precip_in": 0.0,
      "humidity": 88,
      "cloud": 5,
      "feelslike_c": 6.2,
      "feelslike_f": 43.2,
      "windchill_c": 6.2,
      "windchill_f": 43.2,
      "heatindex_c": 7.4,
      "heatindex_f": 45.3,
      "dewpoint_c": 5.6,
      "dewpoint_f": 42.1,
      "will_it_rain": 0,
      "chance_of_rain": "0",
      "will_it_snow": 0,
      "chance_of_snow": "0",
      "vis_km": 10.0,
      "vis_miles": 6.0,
      "gust_mph": 8.1,
      "gust_kph": 13.0,
      "uv": 1.0
    },
    {
      "time_epoch": 1622077200,
      "time": "2021-05-27 02:00",
      "temp_c": 7.1,
      "temp_f": 44.8,
      "is_day": 0,
      "condition": {
        "text": "Partly cloudy",
        "icon": "//cdn.weatherapi.com/weather/64x64/night/116.png",
        "code": 1003
      },
      "wind_mph": 4.5,
      "wind_kph": 7.2,
      "wind_degree": 196,
      "wind_dir": "SSW",
      "pressure_mb": 1018.0,
      "pressure_in": 30.5,
      "precip_mm": 0.0,
      "precip_in": 0.0,
      "humidity": 88,
      "cloud": 5,
      "feelslike_c": 5.9,
      "feelslike_f": 42.6,
      "windchill_c": 5.9,
      "windchill_f": 42.6,
      "heatindex_c": 7.1,
      "heatindex_f": 44.8,
      "dewpoint_c": 5.2,
      "dewpoint_f": 41.4,
      "will_it_rain": 0,
      "chance_of_rain": "0",
      "will_it_snow": 0,
      "chance_of_snow": "0",
      "vis_km": 10.0,
      "vis_miles": 6.0,
      "gust_mph": 8.7,
      "gust_kph": 14.0,
      "uv": 1.0
    }
  ]

}
/* $.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: api + "forecast.json?key=" + apiKey + "&q=" + position.coords.latitude+ "," + position.coords.longitude,
  dataType: 'json',
  timeout: 0,
  success: (parsed_json) => {*/
var htmls = "";
//loop through jsons
$(parsed_json.hour).each(function(i, v) {
  //append htmls...
  htmls += `<div class="card align-items-center justify-content-center text-center" style="width: 7rem;">    
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="title">${v.time.split(" ")[1]}</h5>
      <div class="box"><img src="http:${v.condition.icon}"></div>
      <p class="card-text">${v.temp_c}&#176;</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>`

})
$("#outer").html(htmls) //add them in your dom..
/* }
    });*/
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="outer"></div>
```

Comment: my json is from an api and it will change daily, therefore I would not be able to add it to my code and instead will need to fetch it from the api.

Comment: I cannot replicate ajax in demo code so i have use json  for demo...it will take data from return json result only that's why i have put that `$.each` code inside `success: (parsed_json) =>` . Between you have given downvote ?

Comment: sorry I didn't realise that

Comment: You just need to copy whole code which is inside success function and add them in your code..see if that works .. Also , add `<div id="outer"></div>` in your dom as well.

Comment: I have tried out your code but for some reason it's the same as other answers where the code does not loop through the json. I can't understand why this is happening.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233009/discussion-between-swati-and-becky).

Answer (score 1):

your using jQuery so `$.getJSON` is the same as using `$.ajax` with `dataType` set to `json` https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/ this page even has an example of how to format for HTML output.

Ther is a comment where you can do all your DOMElement Creation/updating, but it uses jQuery's context system https://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery-selector-context

```js
const tpl = `<div class="card align-items-center justify-content-center text-center" style="width: 7rem;">
    
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 id="title"></h5>
      <div id="box"></div>
      <p id="card-text"></p>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>`;

$.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: api + "forecast.json?key=" + apiKey + "&q=" + position.coords.latitude+ "," + position.coords.longitude,
      dataType: 'json',
      timeout: 0,
      success: (parsed_json) => {
          $.each(parsed_json.forecast.forecastday, fucntion(key, val){
                let card = $(tpl);
                $("#box", card).append("<img src='"+val['hour'][0]['condition']['icon']+"'");
                // add the other Elements you want in display here using $("selector", card)
          });
      }
});
```

So above is an example of how you can create the DOM Stucture outside of the DOM then when you finished just select your `card` container E.G `let container = $("#container")` then call append on it `container.append(card);`

Another thing to note this is using jQuery selector with full HTML will create the HTMLObjects and return the topmost element wrapped in the jQuery wrapper so you can manipulate it. E.G `$("<div id='testDiv'></div>")` will return a jQuery wrapped new HTMLDivElement with the attribute id set to "testDiv"

Comment: I will try to give this a go

Comment: Sorry corrected the comment i left tpl as the second param it needs to be card the jQuery Wrapped HTMLElement object created from the tpl

Comment: this sadly one displays one result and doesn't loop thought them

Comment: it's not picking up the key

Comment: @becky I'm not sure they only thing I could say is try not using `$.each` and try using `parsed_json.forecast.forecastday.forEach( function(val, key){ } );`

Answer (score -2):

Try JSON.parse using the reviver parameter - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse#using_the_reviver_parameter

```
    const json = `{ "forecast": {
                        "forecastday": [{
                                "time_epoch": 1622080800,
                        "time": "2021-05-27 03:00",
                        "temp_c": 6.9,
                        "temp_f": 44.4,
                        "is_day": 0,
                        "condition": {
                            "text": "Partly cloudy",
                            "icon": "//cdn.weatherapi.com/weather/64x64/night/116.png",
                            "code": 1003
                        }},
                        {
                        "time_epoch": 1622080800,
                        "time": "2021-05-27 03:00",
                        "temp_c": 6.9,
                        "temp_f": 44.4,
                        "is_day": 0,
                        "condition": {
                            "text": "Partly cloudy",
                            "icon": "//cdn.weatherapi.com/weather/64x64/night/116.png",
                            "code": 1003
                        }
                        },
                        {
 "time_epoch": 1622080800,
                        "time": "2021-05-27 03:00",
                        "temp_c": 6.9,
                        "temp_f": 44.4,
                        "is_day": 0,
                        "condition": {
                            "text": "Partly cloudy",
                            "icon": "//cdn.weatherapi.com/weather/64x64/night/116.png",
                            "code": 1003
                        }}]
                        }}`;
const arr = [];    

const obj = JSON.parse(json, (key, value) => {
    if(key === 'temp_c' || key === 'time' || key === 'condition'){
      arr.push({key, value})
    }
});


console.log(arr);
```

Comment: jQuery's `dataType` set to JSON will do the JSON Parsing for people